# Android WebView swtiching from Numeric input type to Password input type

Tags: android, jquery, keyboard, android-webview

I have a webview where I have 3 input types

1. Number
2. Text
3. Password

When I switch from number to text input field the qwerty keyboard opens up as expected. When I switch from text to password the qwerty keyboard opens up without any suggestions as required and expected. But problem is, when I switch from numeric to password input field the numeric keyboard opens up but I want it to be qwerty so that i may enter alphabets by default in password field

I have done this to override my webview onCreateInputConnection. The below code is irrelevant to this issue as this code was used as a solution to show decimal key on numeric keypad which was not there by default. But i know something needs to be changed here to get my problem solved

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    if ((outAttrs.inputType & InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
    {
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
    }
    else
    {
        outAttrs.inputType |=InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        InputConnection connection = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        return connection;
    }
     return new ExtendedInputConnection(this,false);
}
```

This is ExtendedInputConnection class just for reference. Here i have added method so that backspace keydown event is sent and can be captured by JQuery

```
public class ExtendedInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection implements InputConnection{


public ExtendedInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
    super(targetView, fullEditor);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {       
    // in latest Android, deleteSurroundingText(1, 0) will be called for backspace
    if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
        // backspace
        return super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
    }

    return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would be more useful to you, instead of using `|=` to add more flags, just assign them using `=` operator, otherwise you will be stacking different flags, resulting in a not desired behaviour:

Case 1: `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`

Case 2: `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE`

Case 3: `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`

This should do the trick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But how to add these tags for first case i have added the tag but for password how can i know that the editor info has password as input type so that i may set the InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD

Comment: First of all sorry, you said that you wanted password as text, i took the wrong  flag. Secondly, I dont understand what you mean. You have to check the `InputType` of your EditorInfo in order to apply to a ´EditText´ or there are more "external conditions"?. Could you develop a little bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know in my onCreateInputConnection what type of input did the webview returned, under the if condition as i did with number type field. And then setting the appropriate flag if the input type was password. In short i want to know if the input type was password and if it was i want to set appropriate flag